# How to convert minutes (smallInt) to Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I need to convert my `smallint` variable (number of minutes) into a `datetime`.

```
@duration smallint = 50
@duration smallint = 70
```

How can I add this 70 minutes to current `datetime`?

Comment: What is the expected output for 70?

Comment: 70 minutes. output should be in datetime format

Comment: 70 = Current time + 70 miutes? 70 minutes from midnight of current date? Please be a bit more specific

Comment: sorry....... add 70 minutes to current time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
[GETDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)

```
dateadd(minute, @duration, getdate())
```